# Mark protocol method as deprecated

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, deprecation-warning

How do I make a protocol method appear as deprecated for someone implementing the protocol? I've tried using `@available` as shown below, but there is no warning shown in Xcode when implementing the protocol method.

```
protocol TestDelegate {
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Don't use this anymore")
    func myMethod() -> Bool
}

extension ViewController: TestDelegate {
    func myMethod() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on my experience of [Swift's source code](https://github.com/apple/swift), I've never encountered the `deprecated` argument for the `@available` attribute applied to _blueprints_ of function signatures (i.e. _in_ protocols), only to actual _declarations_ of functions. The ref. docs for states that attributes may only be applied to declarations: possibly these were never intended to be applied to function blueprints (even if e.g. `unavailable` can be applied to blueprinted methods in protocols marked as `@objc`).

Comment: I'm not sure this is currently possible in pure Swift.

Comment: Note also that none of [the tests](https://github.com/jrose-apple/swift/blob/bfa1269cd41b63a5a12172c56e8f96f37ab00806/test/attr/attr_availability.swift) of the `@available` attribute covers protocols. The `@available(_, deprecated, msg)` warning macro is implemented as `availability_deprecated_msg` in [swift/include/swift/AST/DiagnosticsSema.def](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/include/swift/AST/DiagnosticsSema.def), but I don't know in which context/environments this parsing is performed. But in case someone wants to dig on deeper.

Comment: Not sure if this is worth a radar as well, but I've opened [SR-3109](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3109).  The Swift open-source team is usually quick about replying to issues, so we'll see what they say.

Comment: I agree with @dfri even if you see at UIKit framework, there is no warning messages applied to the function signatures in the protocol.

Answer (score 17):

### Info

[About attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID347)

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Code

```
@objc
protocol TestDelegate {
    @available(iOS, unavailable)
    func myMethod1() -> Bool

    @available(iOS, unavailable, message: "Don't use this anymore")
    func myMethod2() -> Bool

    @available(iOS, unavailable, renamed: "myMethod4()")
    func myMethod3() -> Bool

    @available(iOS, obsoleted: 10.0)
    func myMethod4() -> Bool

    @available(swift, introduced: 3.0, obsoleted: 4.2)
    func myMethod5() -> Bool

    @available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, obsoleted: 11.0)
    func myMethod6() -> Bool
}

extension ViewController: TestDelegate {

    func myMethod1() -> Bool { return true }
    func myMethod2() -> Bool { return true }
    func myMethod3() -> Bool { return true }
    func myMethod4() -> Bool { return true }
    func myMethod5() -> Bool { return true }
    func myMethod6() -> Bool { return true }
}
```

### Check

[image]

Comment: What about deprecated, but not obsolete?

Comment: If you use mark your function as deprecated, xCode will not display any warnings, or errors. Only display the crossed-out function in suggest view.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? Is marking the protocol as `@objc` required? The library I'm working on is swift-only, it would be unfortunate if I would have to add `@objc` to a swift-only protocol to deprecate the use of one of the delegate methods.

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk Thank you. Unfortunately I can't use `@objc` because some of the arguments of my delegate function aren't available in Objective-C. Ah well, hopefully people will read the changelog well :). I could create a hack, where I set a static variable in the default implemention of that delegate function, and throw an assert if that static variable isn't set. But that would become way too messy for just marking a function as deprecated.